# Ajax/jQuery website title getter only partially working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, heroku

I have a simple website title getter:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#title").click(function() {

    var SubURL = $("#input").val(); 
    $.ajax({
  url: "http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/"+SubURL+"/",
  complete: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
  }
    });
});
```

});

The way it works is you enter a URL of a website in the $("#input") field and this code will bring up an alert with the title of the website. For example, entering www.bbc.co.uk in the field will alert you with "BBC - Home", the correct title. My problem is, when I enter a more specific url, like www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/39513521/the-illegal-drugs-with-legal-medical-uses my alert gives me "undefined". What do I need to do to get both "BBC - Home" *and* "The illegal drugs with legal medical uses - BBC Newsbeat" from this algorithim?

Comment: The problem appears to lie within how the `textance.herokuapp.com` server code parse the url. I guess it is the slashes `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to urlencode the url

```
http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/www.bbc.co.uk%2Fnewsbeat%2Farticle%2F39513521%2Fthe-illegal-drugs-with-legal-medical-uses%2F
```

---

You could use `encodeURIComponent`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#title").click(function() {

    var SubURL = encodeURIComponent( $("#input").val() );
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/"+SubURL+"/",
      complete: function(data) {
          alert(data.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

The url can't have the protocol either, like `http://`, so with this update,  added `.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, '')`, you get that removed if exists.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#title").click(function() {

    var SubURL = encodeURIComponent( $("#input").val().replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, '') );
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/"+SubURL+"/",
      complete: function(data) {
          alert(data.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Unfortunately, I'm getting two errors in the console: https://pastebin.com/raw/gj5cdyAb, and the same old "undefined" alert. Any further ideas? Edit: The heroku api is giving application errors, even with the old "bbc.co.uk" link. It appears your code worked, but the service is no longer working for some reason

Comment: @user3033668 Yes, you need to remove the protocol part, `http://` (`http%3A%2F%2F`) .... updated my answer

Comment: @user3033668 My above updated code will work as soon as the app is up and running again